# Convergence of $u * \eta_\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, convolution

Let $\eta \in C_c^\infty(B(0,1)), \eta \ge 0, \eta$    radially symmetric and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta d\mathcal{L}^n = 1$. $\eta_r := r^{-n} \eta(\frac{x}{r}) \in C_c^\infty(B(0,r))$. Integral of $\eta_r$ is still 1.

Now we are using a few convergences which I don't get in lecture:

**$L^1$-convergence**

Let $\Omega$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $u \in L^1(\Omega), u_ \epsilon (x) := u*\eta_\epsilon (x)$ (the convolution). Then $u_\epsilon \to u$ in $L^1$ for $\epsilon \to 0$

**Uniform convergence**

Now let $u \in C_c^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $u_\epsilon \to u$ uniformly  (and thus also pointwise)

Also, out of interest: if you drop the compact support of $u$, would it still converge pointwise?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I suppose proofs were given in the lecture? Are there particular points in the proofs that you don't understand?

Comment: @DanielFischer No they weren't or I am overseeing something. Both of these statements are just being used at some points. If proofs where given, then just oral in the lecture. I also would take pointers to where I can find proofs of the statements gladly.

Comment: Did you try to prove that directly?

Comment: @John I Trier with the L1 convergence and have an idea there but it fails. For uniform/pointwise convergence I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|u_\epsilon (x) - u(x)| &= \left|\int_B u(y) \eta_\epsilon (y-x) dy - u(x) \right|\\
&= \left|\int_B (u(y) - u(x)) \eta_\epsilon(y-x) dy \right|\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But the support of $\eta_\epsilon$ is so small, so the integration is over where $|y-x|$ is small. (Then try to use the uniform continuity of $u$).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried for L1 convergence (pulling u(x) into the integral). It works for the uniform convergence as I see. But still no luck with the L1 convergence

Comment: @fubal For the $L^1$ convergence, use that $$\lVert f\ast u_\varepsilon - g\ast u_\varepsilon\rVert_1 = \lVert (f-g)\ast u_\varepsilon\rVert_1 \leqslant \lvert f-g\rVert_1,$$ and that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.